# "ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set" while running r.covar in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin

```
QGIS version: 3.34.3-Prizren
QGIS code revision: 47373234ac
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.18
GDAL version: 3.8.3
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.1, December 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: 3fced5)
Algorithm started at: 2024-03-09T18:12:26
Algorithm 'r.covar' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-r' : True, 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'html' : 'C:/Users/geoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html', 'map' : ['D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b2.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b3.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b4.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b5.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b6.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b7.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b8.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b8a.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b11.tif','D:/Docs/RS_2023/6th/DRS/images/2022_b12.tif'] }
g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/geoka/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mfTTDo/5b1525fa9ecf4522be1f0873ec3eb566/crs.prj"
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b2.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9da8d12" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b3.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9de7513" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b4.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9de7514" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b5.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e25d15" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b6.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e25d16" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b7.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e64117" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b8.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e64118" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b8a.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a19" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b11.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a20" --overwrite -o
r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b12.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9ee1421" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4315680.0 s=4290670.0 e=647950.0 w=622940.0 res=10.0
r.covar map=rast_65ec8a6a9da8d12,rast_65ec8a6a9de7513,rast_65ec8a6a9de7514,rast_65ec8a6a9e25d15,rast_65ec8a6a9e25d16,rast_65ec8a6a9e64117,rast_65ec8a6a9e64118,rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a19,rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a20,rast_65ec8a6a9ee1421 -r > "C:/Users/geoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html" --overwrite
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/geoka/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_mfTTDo/5b1525fa9ecf4522be1f0873ec3eb566/crs.prj"
ERROR: MAPSET is not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b2.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9da8d12" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b3.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9de7513" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b4.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9de7514" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b5.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e25d15" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b6.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e25d16" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b7.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e64117" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b8.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9e64118" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b8a.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a19" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b11.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a20" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.in.gdal input="D:\Docs\RS_2023\6th\DRS\images\2022_b12.tif" band=1 output="rast_65ec8a6a9ee1421" --overwrite -o
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>g.region n=4315680.0 s=4290670.0 e=647950.0 w=622940.0 res=10.0
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>r.covar map=rast_65ec8a6a9da8d12,rast_65ec8a6a9de7513,rast_65ec8a6a9de7514,rast_65ec8a6a9e25d15,rast_65ec8a6a9e25d16,rast_65ec8a6a9e64117,rast_65ec8a6a9e64118,rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a19,rast_65ec8a6a9ea2a20,rast_65ec8a6a9ee1421 -r --overwrite 1>"C:/Users/geoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html"
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
C:\Users\geoka\Documents>exit
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
ERROR: Incomplete GRASS session: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
Press any key to continue . . .
Execution completed in 1.28 seconds
Results:
{'html': 'C:/Users/geoka/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html'}
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'r.covar' finished
HTML output has been generated by this algorithm.
Open the results dialog to check it.
```

This is the full log. It runs, but the resulting covariance report is blank.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.